# Data View for Campaigns?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Does anyone know if there is an undocumented Data View that I could query to obtain the Campaign assignment for an email?  This does not seem to be incorporated into any of the existing data views. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Data View is available for campaigns at the moment, however using the Campaign Email Tracking under Tracking > My Reports > Tracking Reports > ... may provide you an export that you can use to merge/join with an existing Data View.

Comment: Thanks.  Although that won't help with the specifics of what I am trying to do (automatically pass the assigned campaign in a url parameter), that is good to know for other potential needs.

Comment: How to get that campaign report by Query/Data View? @MarkP