# AMPscript system data personalization string for Campaign Name and Campaign Code

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I would like to know if Marketing Cloud supports system data personalization strings (something like `%%emailname_%%` for email name) for Campaign Name and Campaign Code that I can use in HTML body of an email.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a personalization string for Campaigns, see list of available personalization [here](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/)

There also is not a data view available for [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/90132/data-view-for-campaigns) nor is it available via API. Your best bet is to [add it via ampscript variable into a send log](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/103266/campaign-tags-exacttarget).

Comment: Thank you @gortonington for suggestion with the send log. I know that in documentation isn't any personalization string related to Campaigns but as a lot of other things in Marketing Cloud not everything is documented. So I wanted to give a try.